# How to parse an 8-bit hexadecimal number and a string using boost C++?

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

I have just started using boost C++ libraries for some parser work. I would like to use some help on the following:

1. Matching an 8-bit hexadecimal number. I have tried: `char_("0-9a-fA-F")` which matches only one hexadecimal digit. I've also tried using: `*char_("0-9a-fA-F")`, but it is also not working
2. Matching any string with underscore characters? For example, `aBCd_Efgh`

Comment: Never tried boost's regex, but something like `^[0-9a-fA-F]{2}$` and `_` maybe?

Comment: This looks more like Boost Spirit than Boost Regex to me...

Answer (score 3):

Since indeed `char_` is from `boost::spirit::qi` you'll want to simply use the integer parser:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/numeric/int.html

This is easily used to parse hexadecimals:

```
qi::int_parser<unsigned char, 16, 2, 2> hex_byte;
```

will match and parse exactly 2 hexadecimal digits in succession.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PCRE, i.e., initialized your regex like `boost::regex e1(my_expression)` or `boost::regex e2(my_expression, boost::regex::perl)`, then:

1. You can specify a quantifier using brackets (`{min,max}`), so `a{3,10}` would match 3 to 10 `a` characters. You can apply that to a group, like `[0-9a-fA-F]{1,2}`
2. A group expression would do fine: `[0-9a-zA-Z_]+`

If you are using POSIX, the differences are:

1. You need to escape the brackets `\{min,max\}`
2. Nothing.